# WP Pagenavi and Two Different Post Types Incorrect Paging

Tags: wordpress

Anyone know if WP_Pagenavi supports paging a custom archive with two different post types?

For example:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$parameters = array(
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => array('post', 'portfolio')
);

$home_stream = new WP_Query( $parameters );

wp_pagenavi(array('query'=>$home_stream));

// ... do my loop stuff

wp_pagenavi(array('query'=>$home_stream));
```

This results in a correct number of page numbers displayed (in my case 18), but clicking on any pages beyond what would be the number of pages for the first post type (posts, at page 14) results in a 404 for that paged archive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this will answer your question, but this may help.

The below code sets the posts per page in the main query (put this into funcitons.php) of a particular post type.

```
    function wpse_modify_video_archive_query( $query ) {
    // Only apply to the main loop on the frontend.
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query()) {
        return false;
    } 
    if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'video' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
    }
    if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'testimonial' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_modify_video_archive_query' );
```

This sets the video post type posts per page to 6 and testimonial posts per page to 8.

If you want to modify the original query on the page you may want to use

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Before creating your new query.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but the problem is that when the two queries are combined (so, a query for testimonial & video) and paged using WP Pagenavi, WP Pagenavi calculates the number of pages only for the first post type in the array passed to WP_Query, so the number of paged results displayed is right, but pages beyond the count for the first post type result in a 404.

Comment: If you put wp_reset_postdata(); before the start of your query but after $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; does it still give you an error?

Comment: Yes, there are no custom queries elsewhere in the page interfering (they all have wp_reset_postdata(); after them.

Comment: This is such a strange issue, http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html seems to be using "query_posts" as opposed to "new WP_Query" but I think this essentially does the same thing. Other than that I can't see any issues with the code.

Comment: Those instructions are old, he gives instructions for a custom query here: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html, which is what I have in the question.